# "Page.IsValid cannot be called" occurs in Page_PreRender event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently learning ASP.NET, and read that the page validation occurs after Page.Load(). When I put
     if (Page.IsValid == true) whatever;

then I get an error, even though that line is in my Page_PreRender() event handler.

How does that make sense?

Thanks in advance, just trying to understand it fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to have a control that causes validation doing the postback ([`CausesValidation="true"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx)) or actually call [`Page.Validate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validate.aspx) manually for [`Page.IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  to be accessible...otherwise validation hasn't happened, so there's just nothing to check, the value would be meaningless, which is the current error you're seeing.

Comment: Oh alright, I thought it would make more sense to simply have "true" returned when nothing is validated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution does work, I was having problem in OnPageIndexChanging event
I used below code

```
  protected void gvRequests_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
            Page.Validate();
            gvMyRequest.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Populate();
  }
```